# Is it a good sign that I will get a job offer because I received a generic summary benefit package a day after the final interview?

Tags: job-offer

After two weeks of interviewing for a position, I made it to the final interview with another candidate. A day after, the recruiting company sent me an attachment containing a general summary of the company's benefits. The recruiting agency said that the company I interviewed with requested that they send it to me. Is that a good sign that I will get a job offer? I can't see the point of getting that information if they selected the other candidate.

Comment: Don't be anxious. They might have requested that the package should be sent before the interviews. Also, time will tell if you got the job or not. If for a good reason you need to know how the process is going (i.e. you've received a different offer, or will move out the city if you don't start working soon), then there is no point in overthinking every communication with the company as clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is definitely a sign that they wanted you to have that information.

Why they wanted this is probably open to debate, I would say they are considering you as a candidate or it could be part of the onboarding.  Or it could be something standard they were supposed to send out at the beginning but forgot.

Without a crystal ball it is hard to say.

Comment: In the years I have worked for corporations, I never got a benefits package if I was not selected for the position. The benefits were mentioned verbally, but I never received the actual package. When I was chosen for the job, I started receiving information. Drug test form etc. The benefits package was the last piece of information I received as part of the onboarding process.

Comment: @Marylee its absolutely possible that its a good sign but I wouldn't go resigning from your current position based on this document.  It isn't a job offer.  But it isn't a bad sign either.

Comment: I think that the recruiting company should have provided more information in the body of the email rather than just saying, "attached is the summary of benefits."

Answer (score 3):

> Is that a good sign that I will get a job offer?

Don't make that assumption. The other candidate probably got the same information, and it's far more likely that HR is sending that information to any candidate making it to the final rounds. The cost of doing so is small, it'll take an HR agents a few minutes to send this out, but it makes the company look sympathetic, and giving you this information early may speed up the process.

The only question I would have is, why give this information so late in the process? Unless the company benefits are really lousy, you'd like to use them to lure candidates.

Comment: Their benefits package is one of the best I have seen. There were two candidates in the final round. I was one of them. I agree with you that probably the other candidate also got the package while they are still debating to select the right person for the role. It just did not make any sense to me that they will send that information, which has a link to their internal benefits portal if I have not been chosen for the position.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're still at the table, or that they were suppose to send you this before your final interview but they failed to follow up...

Either way, it is really not going to be that long till you know whether you got the job or not. For now, relax but continue to apply to other positions you are interested in. There is nothing certain until you get a written offer for the position.

Comment: I agree. It could be a good sign, but until I received a job offer, it is hard to predict the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that a good sign that I will get a job offer?

No.

When you get an email/verbal from the recruiter telling you to expect one is a good sign that you'll get an offer, or ideally even the letter itself.